# index.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation

Tags: angular, typescript, indexeddb, tslint, tsconfig

I got following error when running 'ng serve'.

> node_modules/angular2-indexeddb/index.ts is missing from the
>   TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via
>   the 'files' or 'include' property. The missing file seems to be part
>   of a third party library. TS files in published libraries are often a
>   sign of a badly packaged library. Please open an issue in the library
>   repository to alert its author and ask them to package the library
>   using the Angular Package Format (https://docs.google.com/document/d/1CZC2rcpxffTDfRDs6p1cfbmKNLA6x5O-NtkJglDaBVs/preview).

I guess the issue is that angular2-indexeddb is not taken into compilation by tsconfig.
https://github.com/gilf/angular2-indexeddb

I think there should be a temporary work around by editting the following configuration in tslint.json, but I need a solution to work through it.

```
  "include": [
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.d.ts"
  ]
```

Is it because angular2-indexeddb doesn't provide a good packaged library? In fact, I don't think a popular published library should have this issue. Or I missed something for configuration or compilation? Can I use package compilation tools/library to compile it into d.ts or spec.ts?

## update:

In fact, I see *.d.ts file in the directory:

```
ls node_modules/angular2-indexeddb/
LICENSE                                 angular2-indexeddb.metadata.json        index.js
README.md                               angular2-indexeddb.min.js               index.js.map
angular2-indexeddb.d.ts                 angular2-indexeddb.min.js.map           index.ts
angular2-indexeddb.js                   angular2-indexeddb.ts                   package.json
angular2-indexeddb.js.map               index.d.ts
```

**Content in tsconfig.json:**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
{
    "include": [
          "../src/**/*",
          "../node_modules/angular2-indexeddb/index.ts"
    ]
}
```

EDIT: I do recommend you change your lib to ngx-indexed-db, so you don't need to do this.

Comment: Is it in the file tsconfig.json under "compilerOptions"? I get the following error: tsconfig.json(18,5): error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'exclude'.

Comment: It's not inside compilerOptions, it's at same level

Comment: I am still seeing the same issue after I add exclude node_modules, I guess it is because I didn't add the files and include. What is the standard tsconfig.json look like? I didn't ever change the tsconfig.json, and it is all okay for other libraries.

Comment: See now edited, try to include that. And if you are using the new CLI version you have to edit it in you tsconfig.app.json

Comment: After adding it, I got new error: <project-root>/src/main.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.

Comment: But have you removed the " * * / *.ts " from includes?

Comment: No, there was no "include" there. But it works fine if I delete the angular2-indexeddb library.

Comment: Thank you, it is working now !! But I am still quite curious why I had no "include" there before I added indexeddb library, why it was working all the time?

Comment: I think it's a problem with the lib, you can see that if you delete the .ts files inside the node_modules/angular2-indexeddb/ will also works, but it's more verbose :). Good that is working now :)

Comment: Thank you. After it is working once, even I revert the tsconfig.app and  tsconfig.app.json as it was, (no include), it is still working. Is it because something didn't compiled?

Comment: I take my last comment back. It is not working if I remove the include

Comment: @AuggieLi If you remove the includes but go to the node_modules/angular2-indexeddb folder and delete the index.ts and angular2-indexeddb.ts it will work, it's a problem with the lib, I will try to open a PR fixing this for them :)

Comment: Thank you. Could you kindly inform me when it is fixed?

Comment: Hi @AuggieLi I several improvements on the lib and now you don't need that configuration to includes in the ts config anymore, you can replace your ng2-indexeddb for this new version: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-indexed-db